# Kubernetes - Ingress / Service / LB

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci

I am new to K8s and this is my first time trying to get to grips with it. I am trying to set up a basic Nodejs Express API using this deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: registry.gitlab.com/<project>/<app>:<TAG>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: api
        env:
        - name: PORT
          value: "8080"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            hostPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry.gitlab.com
```

Which is being deployed via gitlab-ci. This is working and I have set up a service to expose it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-svc
  labels:
    app: api-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: api
  type: LoadBalancer
```

But I have been looking into ingress to have a single point of entry for possibly multiple services. I have been reading through Kubernetes guides and I read through this [Kubernetes Ingress Example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example) and this is the ingress.yml I created:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: api-svc
    servicePort: 80
```

But this did not work, when I visited the external IP address that was generated from the ingress and I just 502 error pages.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, what am I doing wrong or what am I missing? I see that in the example link above that there is an nginx-rc.yml which I deployed exactly like in the example and that was created but still got nothing from the endpoint. The API was accessible from the Service external IP though..

Many Thanks

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with gke last week and decided to give up after some time. Following all the guides to the letter it didn't work and even with others from the k8s slack we couldn't figure out whats wrong. I now decided to just create the ingress load-balancer manually outside kubernetes and point it to my `LoadBalancer` service.

Comment: What did you use for your ingress load balancer outside of Kubernetes? Not sure whether it's an issue because ingress is still in beta but it's weird following their guides and it not working either. Kind of relieved that it's not just me having issues.

Comment: Well the ingress would just create a GCE L7 Loadbalancer - you can even look at it in your Google Cloud Console. So I figured I'd just configure a L7 Balancer in the Console and point it to the L3 Balancer that `LoadBalancer` Service created. (I need it mainly for SSL termination..)

Comment: I see, just looking through that now, how can you point it specifically to the L3 Service/LoadBalancer, I can only point to an instance group which I believe is the entire cluster. This LoadBalancing is totally new to me so sorry if I am mis-understanding something.

Comment: I haven't looked into this in detail yet sorry once I get to it i'll update this answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thought I would post my working deployment/service/ingress**

So after much effort in getting this working, here is what I used to get it working:

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-api-v2
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-api-v2
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: registry.gitlab.com/<project>/<app>:<TAG>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: backend-api-v2
        env:
        - name: PORT
          value: "8080"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            # Path to probe; should be cheap, but representative of typical behavior
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry.gitlab.com
```

**Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-svc-v2
  labels:
    app: api-svc-v2
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 31810
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: backend-api-v2
```

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /v1/*
        backend:
          serviceName: api-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /v2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: api-svc-v2
          servicePort: 80
```

The important bits to notice as @Tigraine pointed out is the service is using `type: NodePort` and not `LoadBalancer`, I have also defined a nodePort but I believe it will create one if you leave it out.

It will use the `default-http-backend` for any routes that don't match the rules this is a default container that GKE runs in the `kube-system` namespace. So if I visited `http://api.foo.com/bob` I get the default response of `default backend - 404`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Also note that health checks have to hit the same port that you are exposing in the service. I did have to abandon the L7 Ingress as the health check is happening on a secondary port I can't expose as it's the main Admin-API Endpoint of my service.

Comment: @Tigraine If I created another deployment and another service does the Ingress create another IP address on GCE ? Is there any way to specify  a static IP  to the Ingress, if any other means to achieve

Comment: @kt14 the ingress is assigned one IP address and proxies the services you describe to it. If you wanted IP address per service you'll need to set up the Services as Load Balancers.

Comment: @mchaffe Yes that's correct, but I wanted to have a single IP address `111.222.333.444` and my services/pods pointing to `www.app1.111.222.333.444` and then I can point my Domain registration to `111.222.333.444` so that all the apps can be accessed as `www.<app-name>.domain.com`

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into it again and think I figured it out.

In order for Ingress to work on GCE you need to define your backend service das a `NodePort` not as ClusterIP or LoadBalancer.

Also you need to make sure the http health check to `/` works (you'll see the Google L7 Loadbalancer hitting your service quite a lot on that url) and then it's available.

Comment: Thanks, after much effort I did get it working, I set up readinessProbes so it gets hit on those endpoints, but also defining a 5sec timeoutSeconds as the 1sec I had set was causing it to fail. I also changed to NodePort as you suggested as well as defining the nodePort in the yml.

Comment: If this was helpful to you I'd appreciate a upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're exposing your service to port `80` but your container is exposing `8080` so any request to the service is going to fail.

Also, have a look at the sample ingress resource (https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/examples/complete-example/cafe-ingress.yaml), you need to also define which hosts / paths route when the ingress controller is hit. (i.e. example.foo.com --> api-svc)

Comment: Thanks @steve currently the service when run as a LoadBalancer is accessible from the outside world. As I understood I thought that using containerPort and hostPort mapped the differences although I may well be wrong. When I accessed the LoadBalancer console and created a custom healthcheck on port 80 the ingress started to work. So it seems there is some port healthcheck issue that prevents it from working by default.